# WPF cascading ComboBoxes not binding when window loads

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I'm using WPF and MVVM, and have a support ticket window that has cascading `ComboBox`es as follows. The first is bound to an `ObservableCollection<ProblemCode>` on the view model. The `ProblemCode` objects have a self-referencing property to their child codes, down to a level of four codes. The XAML for the `ComboBox`es looks like this (simplified, and only three shown for brevity)...

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.ProblemCodes, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Name="ProblemCodeLevel1"
         DisplayMemberPath="Description"
         SelectedValuePath="ID"
         SelectedValue="{Binding ProblemCode1ID, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ProblemCodeLevel1, Path=SelectedItem.Children}"
         Name="ProblemCodeLevel2"
         DisplayMemberPath="Description"
         SelectedValuePath="ID"
         SelectedValue="{Binding ProblemCode2ID, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ProblemCodeLevel2, Path=SelectedItem.Children}"
         Name="ProblemCodeLevel3"
         DisplayMemberPath="Description"
         SelectedValuePath="ID"
         SelectedValue="{Binding ProblemCode3ID, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

When I load a window for a new ticket, the first `ComboBox` is correctly populated. Selecting an item populates the second and so on. When I save the ticket, the data is correctly saved.

However, when I save the ticket and reopen the window, only the first `ComboBox` has the selected item set. The other `ComboBox`es don't have anything set.

I guess that the first `ComboBox` is set as the data is available when the data binding takes place. At that stage, as the first `ComboBox` is data bound, the second one doesn't yet have any items, so doesn't get bound. Same for the third and so on.

Anyone any suggestions as to how to get the binding working? I probably could hack this by adding code to catch various events, but apart from breaking the MVVM pattern, it sounds like none of those situations that would end up convoluted and buggy.

Comment: How does your viewmodel look out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you shouldn't bind directly to elements, you should be binding to properties in your view model. That way you know the property notification is being done properly and you can add breakpoints etc to confirm the bindings are all working as well. In this particular case you need to add something like `SelectedItem="{Binding Level1Item}"` to your first ComboBox and then add a property for it in your view model:

```
public ProblemCode _Level1Item;
public ProblemCode Level1Item
{
    get { return this._Level1Item; }
    set
    {
        if (this._Level1Item != value)
        {
            this._Level1Item = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Level1Item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your second ComboBox binds to this property instead of Element.SelectedItem.Children:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Level1Item.Children}"
    ...etc...
```

Repeat for the second and third ComboBoxes and you'll have the functionality you're after.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. This worked fine, thanks very much.